# Lumia 520 power button is dead after Lumia Black update

Tags: lumia-black-update, buttons, lumia-520

I can't use the power button on my Lumia 520 for anything. It's dead after the Lumia Black update.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a physical damage?

Comment: Sometimes the buttons on my daughter's 520 get stuck because the back cover. It works without the cover?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug . If your Lumia 520 does not wake up, you can force a reboot or  [soft reset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPGPprsmUVU) or [hard reset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPGPprsmUVU). This is possible by holding down the Volume Down and Power buttons together for about 15 seconds or until you feel the phone vibrate. Also you can report it to [windows phone developers](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us).

Comment: This worked for me on my Lumina 820 until I got fed  with having to soft reset all the time to turn on the phone.